# Hide Console Window in Dart on windows

Tags: dart

I want to build  an application with Dart in Windows.
How to hide the console window when application will be start? Like a background service.

Thanks.

Comment: Q: Will your app have a UI?   Q: Have you considered [Flutter Desktop](https://flutter.dev/multi-platform/desktop)?

Comment: No. it's just like a console application but I want to hide The CMD. In C I am using gcc -mwindows And it will be right.

Comment: Q: Will your app have a UI (either a graphical UI, or command-line interaction)? Q: Have you considered [Flutter Desktop](https://flutter.dev/multi-platform/desktop)?  Q: Exactly how are you creating your project and running the program now?

Comment: On Windows, an executable can be either a windowed application or a console application.  Console-mode applications always show a console window.  However, you can use a tool such as `editbin.exe` (included with the Windows SDK) to change the type to a windowed application, which won't show a console window.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424210/

Comment: Yes `editbin.exe` is my solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is kinda a hack where the console window will flash really quickly since the program will spawn the console window but the first line will then hide it again:

```
import 'package:win32/win32.dart';

void main() {
  ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
  // Your program...
}
```

But the rest of your program will then run in the background.

(Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9618984/1953515)

Another ("hacky") solution could be to do what is suggested in the following where we do a change on the generated exe file from `dart compile exe` with `editbin.exe`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2435907/1953515

Comment: Your first suggestion is definitely as good option (+1).  I'd discourage "editbin".  MAIN POINT: I'd really like to get more details from the OP: 1) is this app truly "headless" (like a "service"), or is there *some* UI (even text-mode interaction with the user), 2) How far has the OP gotten with "Dart" (just a source file?  Has he created a project to automate build/run?  Etc.  Etc.)?  3) Is "Dart only" a requirement, or can the OP leverage Flutter (e.g. Flutter Desktop)?

Comment: Yes this is like a service. Without UI

Comment: @MrRookoo - I guess one partial answer to three specific questions is the best I'm going to get today :)  ANYWAY - I'm glad you have what looks like an acceptable solution :)